# Sending string as an attachment using javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I have been trying to get a solution but I am not able to. Here is the whole thing. I wrote the following code

```
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
 message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
 message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
 message.setSubject(subject);
 message.setSentDate(new Date());

 MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
 messagePart.setContent(messageContent, "text/html");
 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
 multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);

 MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment.getBytes(), "text/plain");
 attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
 attachmentPart.setFileName(attachmentFileName);
 multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
 message.setContent(multipart);

 try {
Transport.send(message);                
 } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The code is pretty much self explanatory. messagePart is the mail and attachmentPart is the attachment. But messagePart here is not plain text. It is HTML. So the problem is if I run this code mail is sent successfully but the attachment does not come attached to the mail. So my question boils down to this. Is it possible to send html content and attach something to a mail at the same time. I am stuck here. Could anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

How are you determining that the message has no attachment?

You can see exactly what JavaMail would send by adding "message.writeTo(System.out);" just before you call Transport.send.

What version of JavaMail are you using?  What mail server are you using?  Some mail servers (I'm looking at you, Exchange) will reformat the message to what they think it should be, even if it's different than what you intended.

Comment: Javamail version is 1.4.3. And I run this code on Google App Engine. Could that be the problem behind everything?

Comment: Added a dummy text part and it works fine. Thanks a lot for the help guys

Comment: Yep! Adding a dummy text part worked for me too - also on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add

```
attachmentPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
```

`Part.ATTACHMENT` means the part should be showed as an attachment.

`Part.INLINE` means you want to show the attachment as part of the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **running on Google App Engine** and you add a dummy text part it works great. I have no idea why the dummy text part makes it work, but I was having the exact same problem and adding a dummy text part worked for me too.